# Connect to 2 IP cameras (servers) from laptop

Tags: c#, .net

I am completely new to coding, I needed suggestions on this issue,

I need to connect my laptop to 2 IP cameras (servers), and fetch data from them continuously. I could get data from one camera continuously. I need some help so that I know how to get data simultaneously from both IP cameras at a time. both cameras have different IP adress.

Comment: Get yourself a book about coding.

Comment: We need to know what cameras they are, what the API is (JSON/IP/TCP/UDP/XML/etc), and more to answer what you are actually wanting.


To answer what you've actually asked: Spawn 2 tasks that each spin in an infinite while loop pulling data, and block in your main thread.

Comment: There are some components that can display streaming jpeg, you might want to start there.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. The goal of this site is to solve specific programming problems. Please start by reading [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and then rewrite your question to include more detailed info about your goals, specific setup and current solution. As for the question stated as it is, we can only guess your situation. You should probably try to do what you did with one camera, but on separate threads.